# xslt 1.0: sorting elements across multiple documents

Tags: xml, function, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a search result in an xml documents (called result.xml) as a list of references to container documents (mycore.xml) which refer to the "real" content file (mets.xml) in a another document.  The problem arrises when not only to format the third level document but sort the whole result based on an element on the third level document (the year of the publication dataIssued) in the mets.xml document.  Here a rough picture of that:

```
/result/doc/@href --> document('mycore_1.xml')/mycore/file/@href -> document('mets_1.xml')/mets/dmdSec
       /doc/@href --> document('mycore_2.xml')/mycore/file/@href -> document('mets_2.xml')/mets/dmdSec
```

I have a solution using a XSLT 2.0 function but didn't got that working using call or apply template in XSLT 1.0.  Unfortunately, in the CMS of choice, typo3, I just can use a XSLT 1.0 processor.

result.xml

```
<result>
  <doc href="mycore_1.xml"/>
  <doc href="mycore_2"/>
  ...
</result>
```

mycore_1.xml

```
<mycore>
  <file href="mets_1.xml">
</mycore>
```

mets_1.xml

```
<mets>
  <dmdSec>
    <mods>
      <dataIssued>1980
      </dateIssued>
      <namePart>Jones
      </namePart>
       ...
    </mods>
  </dmdSec>
</mets>
```

Here is for XSLT 2.0 a function definition that works for me.

```
<!-- returns a node-set of all dmdSec -->
<xsl:function name="mets:fetchFiles">
  <xsl:param name="docs"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$docs">
    <xsl:for-each select="document(@href)/mycore/file">
       <xsl:for-each select="document(@href)/mets/dmdSec">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>
```

And here the call and sorting:

```
<xsl:for-each select="fetchFiles(result/doc)">
  <xsl:sort select="mods/dateIssued"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="theFormatting">
  ... <!-- format and output the dmdSec/mods -->
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The difficulty for me seems to be, that the copy-of in the function returns a
modified input but with call-template I just produce with copy-of output.
Is there a way to replace the input to allow for sorting and formatting
the dmdSec element and subelements?

Any response would be appreciated!

Holger

Answer (score 1):

Well if you wanted to implement the XSLT 2.0 function in XSLT 1.0 you could do that as a template which would then return a result tree fragment you could convert into a node-set (with `exsl:node-set($rtf)`) for sorting.

But frankly I don't see why you take all those steps, the `document` function is powerful enough to process several nodes and to return several documents so you should be able to use

```
<xsl:for-each select="document(document(result/doc/@href)/mycore/file/@href)/mets/dmdSec">
  <xsl:sort select="mods/dateIssued"/>
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

respectively I would prefer to and suggest to use apply-templates e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document(document(result/doc/@href)/mycore/file/@href)/mets/dmdSec">
  <xsl:sort select="mods/dateIssued"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

and have

```
<xsl:template match="mets/dmdSec">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: My understanding of the problem with the nested document() call is, that node-set arguments to document are evaluated to the first element of that node-set.  So, I end up just with one of my dmdSec element not the whole node-set of all dmdSec from all referenced documents.  But thanks for the first idea of using the node-set-function for sorting. I will try that.

Comment: You are understanding of the `document` function is wrong, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document. If for instance `result/doc/@href` selects three `href` attributes, each with a file name or more general, a URI, then the `document` call returns a union of three documents.

Comment: Great, thanks to clearify that.  Your solution #2 worked great for me with the saxon xslt prcoessor.  Still wondering, what went wrong with xslite in typo3, but seems to be a problem not related to xslt.  Thanks again!  Holger

Comment: Found the source of trouble, I left out a important detail in my posting.  In fact the first URL should be rewritten by something like concat(@href, '?style=derivatedetails'), and that rendered the call to document() useless.  So, I suppose that I have to try using exsl:node-set().